# Euclidean distance between two items and a reference into probability

Tags: probability, geometry

Let's say I have two items $A$ and $B$ and a reference item $R$.
I know that items $A$ and $R$ belong to the same class while $B$ belongs to a different one (I don't know if this can influence the probability).

I know the Euclidean distance $d(A,R)$ and $d(B,R)$. I would like to obtain a probability to choose $A$ over $B$ regarding the previously obtained distances, where $P(A) + P(B) = 1$.

Thanks in advance!

EDIT: I'm looking for similarity, thus the shorter distance has bigger probability.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming, that at least one distance is nonzero, set $$P(A)=\frac{d(A,R)}{d(A,R)+d(B,R)}$$ and similarly $P(B)$.

Comment: I think the function would penalize the longer distances while I'm looking for similarity, thus the shorter distance the bigger probability (edited the question)

Comment: Maybe applying $s(A,R)=\frac{1}{1+d(A,R) }$ as the function of similarity and then using $P(A) = \frac{s(A,R)}{s(B,R)}$ could work. If $d(A,R)=0$ it means that the items are really similar so $s(A,R)=1$. In the opposite case $d(A,R)=\infty$ they are dissimilar and $s(A,R)=0$.

Comment: @ManuelLagunas  Yeah, you can do that, s(A,R) works, but be careful with $P(A)$: as you have it is not a probability. Do again $P(A)=\frac{s(A,R)}{s(A,R)+s(B,R)}$

Comment: yeah thanks!. Sorry had a typo defining $P(A)$ now I cannot edit

Comment: @ManuelLagunas Great then, you got it by yourself